# How to avoid multiple runs of a console application without losing data to be processed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I've to program a console application with the given scenario. We have a web application that is interacting with a SQL server database. It is a third party application with no control from our side. The application writes user generated data into a table inside the database. After writing the data, the application provides a way to invoke a console application to further process the data and insert it into its relavant tables.

The issue is that since the application is a web application, multiple users can generate data simultaneously, and hence, the console application can be invoked multiple times. Once the application runs multiple times, it reads data from the temporary table in the first run, and later runs register errors for data not found (since it has already been processed by the first instance of the console application).

I've tried to use a Mutex in the console application for stopping the application from running if an earlier instance of the application is already active. However, the issue I've faced with it is that when the first instance of the console application reads the data and empties the table, the second instance of the ***web*** application might still be active and can still dump some data in the temporary table (after the first run of the console application has finished reading the table). This leaves dangling unprocessed data in the temporary table, since subsequent runs of the console application have already been stopped due to Mutex unavailability.

How can I solve this conundrum?

Comment: Do you control the inital load of data into the temp table before the console app is invoked.   Could you queue up and sequentially load the temp data yourself before the console app is run.

Comment: You could add a nullable guid column to the temp table. Then each time the console app starts, it generates a new guid, updates the temp table with the guid (for rows where the col is null) and then it processed only the rows with its own guid. After processing, it removes the rows with its own guid. Then you can have several instances of the console app running at the same time without them trying to process the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handling the concurrency issues at the application level, try  instead to handle it at the database level.

The strategy here would be to employ [pessimistic concurrency control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx#Lock_Basics) on the table where the data is being staged. The tactic here is to allow the select query of the console application to apply locks on the data that being accessed.  This causes any subsequent instances of the application to wait until the locks are released before having access to the table.  Techniques such as row level locks and SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable could be employed.

Since we don't want adverse impact to the web application, I would suggest the following strategy:

1. Create a new staging table and trigger on the database to move (insert/delete) from the source table to the staging table.  This will be the table that the console application will work from.
2. Eliminate mutex from the console application, however, ensure that the database connection timeout is sufficient.
3. Select/update/delete statements should allow for granular locking/isolating of row level data until the job is complete. Ensure to avoid deadlocks.

**For more reference:**

- See the "Managing Concurrent Data Access" section of [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx).
- Understand isolation level [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).